# Orientation and Cocos2d Problems on iOS8.3

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, orientation, uiinterfaceorientation, ios8.3

I am having Orientation and `Cocos2D` problems in iOS8.3

Before, I was using

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDeviceOrientation:CCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
```

and also for mixing UI Kit with Cocos2D i am using
a

```
rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(2*M_PI-1.57079633);
[self.view setTransform:rotate]
```

or

```
rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.57079633);
        [self.view setTransform:rotate];
```

Now the old technique seems to not work.

Removing everything and the `CCDirector` orientation calls, the app will load up in portrait with black space at the top.

If I do landscape Right, it looks like buttons at the top are fine, but bottom stuff are offset.

If I do landscape Left, it looks like everything is offset to the right, with extra black space on the left.

I tried all combinations of `checking/unchecking` orientations, removing calls to `CCDirector` for orientations, and removing my affine transform rotations, all to no avail.

What did 8.3 Change to break my `COcos2D` app ?

Comment: Was it working in iOS 8.2, or 8.0?  Yes there were changes from 7.0 to 8.0, but none that I know of since then.